# Why is this Java code always giving me "False" statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, input, passwords

When I type the same password (jalalkay) it gives me "False" answer!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class password2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner pass = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Type a password");
        String ps = pass.nextLine();

        if(ps == "jalalkay"){
            System.out.println("true");

        }else{
            System.out.println("false");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `ps.equals("jalalkay")`. You don't compare Strings with the equality operator.

Comment: Because you should use .equals() to compare Strings, not ==

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using == to compare Strings. This is incorrect. Use `.equals()` instead.

```
if(ps.equals("jalalkay")){
    System.out.println("true");
```

The == operator checks for reference comparison (address comparison) and `.equals()` method checks for content comparison. To put it another way, == checks if both objects point to the same memory location and `.equals()` evaluates to the comparison of values in the objects.